# Get data from odk Aggregate

Tags: odk

I want to get form data using api's.

```js
http://localhost:8080/ODKAggregate/view/submissionList?formId=abcd returns me a list of uuid's like: 

    <id>uuid:52af4a39-bf13-4305-b1a6-2b02d839dd7c</id>
<id>uuid:2e988c5b-8160-4d59-b2ee-6fe0728416bf</id>
<id>uuid:02c67418-8922-491d-a345-d41d223db949</id>
<id>uuid:4e06eb89-3f2c-4cef-b82b-38b725080c95</id>
<id>uuid:a3e2da91-719d-458d-bf9a-f15f4406eee7</id>
<id>uuid:19ff4408-0f6c-4e37-9d48-ecfb6d74b4e1</id>
```

Now I want to download each submission individually using downloadSubmission api described here https://github.com/opendatakit/opendatakit/wiki/Briefcase-Aggregate-API

Can anybody tell what will be the exact format to call downloadSubmission?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

../view/downloadSubmission?formId=YOURFORMID[@version=null@uiVersion=null]/**YOURFORMID2***[@key=uuid:xyz]

***Look this up prefixed with each question in your form's XML**